# input image dimensions for CNN in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow records and CNN for a image classification / segmentation problem. I am looking for an approach to feed the network with training images of varying-dimensions. At present, I'm just resizing all images using `tf.image_resize_with_crop_or_pad()` function. There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616503/feeding-a-convolutional-neural-network-with-variable-sized-inputs-in-tensorflow) but I'm usure if that is the correct way. Appreciate help.

By the way, I'm using tensorflow records to feed my model.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Sorry if my post was unclear. The question is "Is it possible to feed variable sized images when using batch-wise training of a CNN in tensorflow ?If yes, how?"

Comment: @user1050648 have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad` you can also try [`tf.image.resize_images`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/image.html#resize_images) which interpolate images to your desired size but may distort your images.

Comment: I'm actually trying to avoid any form of resizing. My question is whether its possible to feed images directly without any modifications to the dimensions.

Comment: If your images have different sizes, then it is impossible to feed your images.

Answer (score 0):

To feed different size of inputs to a tf model is not possible.

One way to handle it without messing up the quality of the images is:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, 
                                                target_size = (150, 150))
```

Where train_dir is where your input is stored, and you can define a constant target size, for the inputs.

Just make sure to do this for the testing images as well.

Comment: This would resize all the images to `[150 x 150]` which is clearly **NOT** what the OP wants. Also, resizing all the images to a square dimension will distort the images as the original impact ratio would be changed.