# How to setup a variable Placeholder shape in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I defined those symbolic placeholders:

```
t_im0 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None, None, 3])
t_im1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None, None, 3])
t_mask = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None, None, 1])
```

Later on, I want to optimize my image values.

```
for obj in images:
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={t_im0: obj.l_img, t_im1.eval(): obj.r_img.eval(), t_mask: obj.mask.eval()})
```

When I execute the code for optimization, I get following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape [1,-1,-1,3] has negative dimensions
 [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[1,?,?,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

My problem is that my images have different shapes. How can I solve loading them without resizing all images on disk?

Comment: You can keep the images as jpeg of different sizes, then use `tf.imag.decode_jpeg` and then resize the images to fixed size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have enough reputation to comment on your question directly, so I will share my thoughts here.

I assume that you are trying to train a convolutional neural network. The problem with that is, that CNNs do not accept variable input sizes. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37618373/4573131) answer can help you understand this problem.